# Set jQuery animation time to pixel distance scrolled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to have a div animate over a number of pixels scrolled, rather than over time. So over the course of scrolling 800 pixels an animation should occur, with a div moving from right to left (0 to -200%).

Is it possible to do this? I wanted to put a var in, kinda like this:

```
var time = 800 + 'px';

$("#div1").animate({
  left: '-200%';
}, time);
```

instead of the usual

```
$("#div1").animate({
  left: '-200%';
}, 1000);
```

or something to this effect. I haven't been able to get it working thus far, and I'm not sure if it's even possible.

EDIT:

In effect I am looking to create a parallax effect. I should have added that the position of #div1 is fixed.

HTML:

```
<div id="1" style="position:fixed;width:300%;">
 <div class="textSlide" style="width:33.33%">Heading One</div>
 <div class="textSlide" style="width:33.33%">Heading Two</div>
 <div class="textSlide" style="width:33.33%">Heading Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like a parallax effect, where the position of an element is set by a factor of the scroll position of the window. Is that what you mean?

Comment: A sample of your HTML would help too.

Comment: At least now you know what to search

Comment: Do you mean move 800px per second? That case, just caculate the time by width / 800.